# Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, snow

I'm using R and I'm running a parallel code on 7 cores on a Linux machine.

When using a small dataset, my code takes about 2 hours and works fine.
When using a 6x larger dataset, the codes takes much longer (probably because it needs to swap), but then will randomly end, sometimes at 10%, sometimes at 18, 20, 30% or so. Looks totally random. RAM usage is usually at about 90%, SWAP usage at <50%.

I'm using `foreach` with the `doSNOW` backend.
This is the error code:

```
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
Calls: %dopar% ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

 *** caught bus error ***
address 0x7f829d2adbd0, cause 'non-existent physical address'
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

And this is the SNOW outfile obtained by setting `outfile="outfile.out"` in the `makeCluster` call:

```
starting worker for localhost:11567 
Type: EXEC 
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: sp

Attaching package: 'raster'

The following objects are masked from 'package:MASS':

    area, select


Attaching package: 'data.table'

The following object is masked from 'package:raster':

    shift

Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 

 *** caught bus error ***
address 0x7ffada863636, cause 'non-existent physical address'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double", as.integer(ncid), as.integer(varid),     as.integer(c.start), as.integer(c.count), fixmiss, imvstate,     as.double(passed_missval), PACKAGE = "ncdf4")
 2: ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,     scaleFact, start = start, count = count, verbose = verbose,     signedbyte = signedbyte, collapse_degen = collapse_degen)
 3: getfun(nc, varid = zvar, start = start, count = count)
 4: .readBrickCellsNetCDF(x, cells, layer, nl)
 5: .cellValues(x, i)
 6: .doExtract(x, i, drop = drop)
 7: por[i]
 8: por[i]
 9: as.vector(por[i])
10: mainF(as.vector(por[i]))
11: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
12: eval(.doSnowGlobals$expr, envir = .doSnowGlobals$exportenv)
13: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
14: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
15: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
16: tryCatch(eval(.doSnowGlobals$expr, envir = .doSnowGlobals$exportenv),     error = function(e) e)
17: fun(quote(list(i = 23339L)))
18: do.call("fun", lapply(args, enquote))
19: docall(msg$data$fun, msg$data$args)
20: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
21: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
22: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
23: tryCatch(docall(msg$data$fun, msg$data$args), error = handler)
24: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
25: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
26: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
27: tryCatch({    msg <- recvData(master)    cat(paste("Type:", msg$type, "\n"))    if (msg$type == "DONE") {        closeNode(master)        break    }    else if (msg$type == "EXEC") {        success <- TRUE        handler <- function(e) {            success <<- FALSE            structure(conditionMessage(e), class = c("snow-try-error",                 "try-error"))        }        t1 <- proc.time()        value <- tryCatch(docall(msg$data$fun, msg$data$args),             error = handler)        t2 <- proc.time()        value <- list(type = "VALUE", value = value, success = success,             time = t2 - t1, tag = msg$data$tag)        sendData(master, value)    }}, interrupt = function(e) NULL)
28: slaveLoop(makeSOCKmaster(master, port))
29: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
30: eval(quote({    master <- "localhost"    port <- ""    snowlib <- Sys.getenv("R_SNOW_LIB")    outfile <- Sys.getenv("R_SNOW_OUTFILE")    args <- commandArgs()    pos <- match("--args", args)    args <- args[-(1:pos)]    for (a in args) {        pos <- regexpr("=", a)        name <- substr(a, 1, pos - 1)        value <- substr(a, pos + 1, nchar(a))        switch(name, MASTER = master <- value, PORT = port <- value,             SNOWLIB = snowlib <- value, OUT = outfile <- value)    }    if (!(snowlib %in% .libPaths())) .libPaths(c(snowlib, .libPaths()))    library(methods)    library(snow)    if (port == "") port <- getClusterOption("port")    sinkWorkerOutput(outfile)    cat("starting worker for", paste(master, port, sep = ":"),         "\n")    slaveLoop(makeSOCKmaster(master, port))}), new.env())
31: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
32: eval(expr, p)
33: eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
34: local({    master <- "localhost"    port <- ""    snowlib <- Sys.getenv("R_SNOW_LIB")    outfile <- Sys.getenv("R_SNOW_OUTFILE")    args <- commandArgs()    pos <- match("--args", args)    args <- args[-(1:pos)]    for (a in args) {        pos <- regexpr("=", a)        name <- substr(a, 1, pos - 1)        value <- substr(a, pos + 1, nchar(a))        switch(name, MASTER = master <- value, PORT = port <- value,             SNOWLIB = snowlib <- value, OUT = outfile <- value)    }    if (!(snowlib %in% .libPaths()))         .libPaths(c(snowlib, .libPaths()))    library(methods)    library(snow)    if (port == "")         port <- getClusterOption("port")    sinkWorkerOutput(outfile)    cat("starting worker for", paste(master, port, sep = ":"),         "\n")    slaveLoop(makeSOCKmaster(master, port))})
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
```

The code is using 7 threads out of 8 of a local machine. The foreach call is made like so:

```
#Packages
packageVec <- c("RcppRoll", "FAdist", "fitdistrplus", "minpack.lm", "raster", "foreach", "data.table")
#Register cluster
cl <- makeCluster(nThreads, outfile=paste0(dischargefile, ".out"))
registerDoSNOW(cl)
#Create progress bar
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = ncells, style = 3)
progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
SNOWopts <- list(progress = progress)
#Compute
a <-
    foreach(i=cells, .packages=packageVec, .combine='rbind', .options.snow = SNOWopts) %dopar% {
      mainF(as.vector(por[i]))
    }
stopCluster(cl)
```

## mainF() function description

It's hard to produce a MRE for this function, as it is complicated. The code is [here](http://pastebin.com/bip1UXvn), and I'll describe what the function does below. I want to stress the fact that all of this works wonderfully on a small dataset, but fails on a large dataset, even if it contains the same data of the small dataset replicated several times.

`mainF()` is a function whose input, `por[i]`, is a 125000 element vector and whose output a 244 element vector. This function basically performs 240 rolling means on the input vector (using `RcppRoll`) and takes the maxima (using `data.table`) for each time slice (usually 15) for each mean, fits the data to a given distribution (using `FAdist`, `raster` and `fitdistrplus`), performs another loop for calculating another 240 values and fits (using `minpack.lm`) those values to a function to obtain more parameters. The 240 elements returned and the 4 fit parameters (2 for each fits) are returned.

How can I fix the above error? What does it mean?

Comment: `serialize` and `unserialize` are functions used to save and restore objects in R respectively. To learn more read `?serialize`. Both use connections to save and read R objects. The coding format used is platform-indepedent, which means objects can be moved between machines without any problem.

Comment: for example: `a1 <- serialize(letters, NULL)`; `a1`;  `unserialize(a1)` will convert the letters into binary form and then back to ASCII characters.

Comment: The above example uses a NULL connection in `serialize` function

Comment: @Sathish Thank you for the explanation, any idea on how I could tackle the problem?

Comment: What is mainF function? Please provide minimal example data as well.

Comment: Try foreach(i=cells, .packages=packageVec, .combine='rbind', .options.snow = SNOWopts) %dopar% {
      myout <- mainF(as.vector(por[i])); return(myout)
    }

Comment: What is your packageVec vector contains ? Please edit your question

Comment: In the end, do an explicit stopCluster(cl)

Comment: @Sathish I added info, see edited answer. I closed the cluster later in the code. The list of packages is provided. I cannot provide a MRE for `mainF()`, but I provided some details. The input data is a vector of numerics, no other constraint is provided. The vector may contain NAs but they are removed inside the function together with values <=0. In short, the function does nothing too strange, just some arithmetic on the vector and some fits.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you show the values of `cells` and `por` by doing `head(cells, 10)` and `head(por, 10)`

Comment: My guess is that you may have problem with the data of `cells` or `por`.

Comment: you mentioned `then will randomly end, sometimes at 10%, sometimes at 18, 20, 30% or so.`. Could you take a sample of 5% and 11% of your data and do the foreach, since 10% of your data fails.

Comment: also try to find the cell value that fails. `a <- foreach(i=cells, .packages=packageVec, .combine='rbind', .options.snow = SNOWopts) %dopar% {
   tryCatch(b1 <- as.vector(por[i]), error = function(c) paste("cell value = ", i));
   c1 <- mainF(b1);
   return(c1);
}`

Comment: use `tryCatch()` as shown in the above comment

Comment: once you know the cell value `i`, you can check validity of `por[i]`

Comment: you can also debug your code by 'Browsing on error' as shown by Hadley here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html

Comment: @Sathish I have dne what you suggested, but got only the usual error, with the call: `Calls: %dopar% ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>     `    . The cluster output file is this: http://pastebin.com/A04bPbGs    . The code is something like this: http://pastebin.com/vZj4Yw1Z

Comment: do `result <- mainF(inputVec);  return(result)` You have to assign the output of the function to a variable and then return it.

Comment: first try with 5 cells and if it works then go on with the full data set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121809/discussion-between-af7-and-sathish).

Comment: @AF7 Did you ever solve this? I get the exact same error msg.

Comment: @jO. I do not think I did, although it's hard to recall. I now use `future` as a parallel package, it works wonderfully.